# Filter JSON to get the specific value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var vJson = 
    '{"tpaCo":[{"name":"Audit Company1", \
                         "aud":[{"name":"auditor1","asgn":"1","fnds":"1","lead":"1"}, \
                                {"name":"auditor2","asgn":"1","fnds":"0","lead":"1"}, \
                                {"name":"auditor3","asgn":"0","fnds":"1","lead":"0"}, \
                                {"name":"auditor4","asgn":"1","fnds":"1","lead":"0"}, \
                                {"name":"auditor5","asgn":"1","fnds":"1","lead":"0"}, \
                                {"name":"auditor6","asgn":"0","fnds":"1","lead":"0"}, \
                                {"name":"auditor7","asgn":"1","fnds":"1","lead":"0"}, \
                                {"name":"auditor8","asgn":"1","fnds":"1","lead":"0"}, \
                                {"name":"auditor9","asgn":"0","fnds":"1","lead":"0"}, \
                                {"name":"auditor10","asgn":"1","fnds":"1","lead":"0"}, \
                                {"name":"auditor11","asgn":"1","fnds":"1","lead":"0"}]}, \
                        {"name":"Audit Company2", \
                         "aud":[{"name":"auditor3","asgn":"0","fnds":"0","lead":"1"}, \
                                {"name":"auditor4","asgn":"0","fnds":"0","lead":"0"} \
                               ] \
                        } \
                      ]}';
      var vObj =  JSON.parse(vJson);
```

Is there any way to filter the JSON object. 
for example i want to search **auditor1** **asgn** value. filter can be dynamic like it can be auditor1 or auditor11. also i want to knw how can i convert the above json into array. which will make my search easy(in case there is no way to search by direct JSON search).

Comment: You can use Array' `filter` method

Comment: how to convert this into an array ?

Comment: After using `JSON.parse` your `tpaCo` property turns to Array automatically. And `aud`s too

Comment: Are you interested in auditor1 across companies or only within a given company?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

**UPD** [example](http://jsfiddle.net/97rQ6/)

USAGE

```
var jsonfilter = new JSONDataFilter(data);
//jsoonfilter.filter(parentNode, parentNodeValue, childrenNode, childNode, childNodeValue)
jsonfilter.filter('name', 'AuditCo1', 'auds', 'asgn', 1);
jsonfilter.filter('id', '2', 'auds', 'name', 'au2');
```

OUTPUT

```
[{name:aud3, asgn:1},{name:aud5, asgn:1},{name:aud6, asgn:1}]
```

JSONDataFilter

```
function JSONDataFilter(data){
    _data = {};
    var construct = function(data){
        _data = data;
    }

    this.filter = function(parent, parentValue, childSet, child, childValue){
        var result = [];
        for(var parentAttr in _data){
            if(_data[parentAttr][parent] != parentValue){
                continue;
            }
            var children = _data[parentAttr][childSet];
            for(var childAttr in children){
                if(children[childAttr][child] == childValue){
                    result.push(children[childAttr]);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
    construct(data);
}
```

Comment: Eg : I pass auditor1 and it should give me asgn= 1,fnds= 1,lead = 1

Comment: if you want to search in company with id = 1, and auditor name = auditor1 jsonfilter.filter('id', '1', 'auds', 'name', 'auditor1'); I have added link to jsfiddle